# How to use Hibernate orphanRemoval with DtoMapping and @Audited

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have audited parent and child entity classes with a one-directional OneToMany mapping. I have DTO classes with the same fields for both (including `id`) and a Mapper that maps from DTO to entities.
If in the DTO class `id` field is set, the `Mapper.map(ParentDto parentDto, Parent.class)` method will not instantiate a new instance of Parent entity, but load the entity from database by its id and then map fields on the loaded entity. When mapping the `childs` `Mapper.map(ChildDto parentDto, Child.class)` method also tries to load the child from database by its id.

My problem is, that before mapping the childs list, the mapper clears the list -> `orphanRemoval = true` triggers and deletes the children from database. They then have to be recreated by the Mapper and persisted. To prevent this I use `session.detach(parent)` on the parent entity before mapping, thus preventing any change to the database and later reattach it by `session.saveOrUpdate(parent)`. This leads to a `NonUniqueObjectException`

The Mapper works like this:

```
@Stateless
public class Mapper{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "core")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void map(ParentDto parentDto, Parent parent) {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        if em.contains(parent) {
            session.detach(parent); //detach so that orphanRemoval will not delete childs from DB
        }

        ...

        parent.getChilds().clear;
        for (ChildDto childDto : parentDto.getChilds()) {
            parent.getChilds().add(mapToEntity(childDto));
        }
        session.saveOrUpdate(parent); //(re-)attach, so that changed fields or new childs get written to DB
    }

    public Parent mapToEntity(ParentDto parentDto) {
        Parent parentEntity= null;
        if (parentDto.id != null) {
            parentEntity= loadParentEntityFromDb(parentDto.id);
        }
        if (parentEntity= null) {
            parentEntity= new Parent();
        }
        map(parentDto, parentEntity);
        return parentEntity;
    }


    public Child mapToEntity(ChildDto childDto) {
        Child childEntity= null;
        if (childDto.id != null) {
            childEntity= loadChildEntityFromDb(childDto.id);
        }
        if (childEntity= null) {
            childEntity= new Child();
        }
        map(childDto, childEntity);
        return childEntity;
    }
}
```

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    ...

    @Getter
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "PARENT_TO_CHILD", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private final List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and Child entity

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

the Dto Classes:

```
public class ParentDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    ...

    @Getter
    private final List<ChildDto> childs = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ChildDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

With this setup during the mapping I then get

```
12:35:17,422 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-5) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff0a00100f:4b2caaeb:5e4cf8b3:58b38, org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization@1149eaa7 >: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [PARENT_TO_CHILDS_AUD#{REV=Revision [id=98781, timestamp=1582112117394, username=RUser], Parent_id=885752, childs_id=885754}]
```

What **does** work, is if I use `em.detach(parent)` and then after mapping `em.merge(parent)`. But merge returns a **copy** of parent that is persistent, the `parent` given to the mapper stays detached. I can not change the signature of the mapping method `public void map(ParentDto parentDto, Parent parent)`, that is why I tried using `session.saveOrUpdate(parent)` in the first place, as this is supposed to only work on the given object and reattach that.

So is there a way to either get the `@Audit` annotation working with `session.saveOrUpdate()`, or to prevent hibernate to delete children (that are orphans for a fraction of a second) during the mapping without changing the clearing of the list before mapping?

I am using Hibernate 5.3.6.Final.

Comment: Clearing and repopulating collections is a bad idea - as you are finding. Can't you match the child ids and add/update/remove as necessary.

Comment: @AlanHay Actually I use a mapping framework (orika) that I have found is working as described above and I cannot change the usage of it and neither how it works.